# Multiple Android AVDs hang on start-up

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried a few AVDs, several APIs and several versions of Android, but it always does the same thing. The AVD starts but it never shows the Android Home Screen, only the logo and it never advances. 
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on x86 hardware. 
I have been searching for info about this problem, but I have not found a solution. I think that this problem has occurred before though and it has a simple solution.

[image: ImageA]
[image: ImageB]

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the RAM you have assigned to the android virtual device this should work.
If this diesnt work then try this.
Look under C:Users\YourUserName\ .android if you can find there a folder named \avd containing subfolders named after the android virtual devices you created. If that is not the case (as it was on my machine) then you probably have moved long ago your account's user data via a symbolic link to some different location, as it was the case in my system. Eclipse (the virtual device manager of the ADK) will create the virtual devices there, but will search for them in the Windows default C:Users\YourUserName\ .android path.

Locate the real folder with your user data, in my case it was: D:\Win\Users\YourUserName where I finally found the AVD-folders needed for Eclipse: D:\Win\Users\YourUserName\ .android\avd...(2 Subfolders with the avd's)

Just copy the avd-folder (in my Example) D:\Win\Users\YourUserName\ .android\avd to the "usual" Location, where Eclipse looks for it, to C:\Users\YourUserName\ .android

Comment: I tried with several ram sizes but  the problem was the same. The AVDs are in the correct place (C:Users\YourUserName\ .android/avd) where i have AVD_for_3_3_WQVGA.avd   and Nexus_5_API_21.avd. I used the AVD with  Android Studio and standalone executed it from terminal ( i thought that problem was of Android Studio) but the problem was the same.

Answer (score 0):

What are your computer's specs? And be sure you have HAXM enabled. [This](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/how-to-use-the-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm-android-emulator) should walk you through the steps to do so (At least for Google API system images). I had a similar problem where I couldn't get past the startup logo on any virtual device aside from the smallest device with the oldest system API. It ended up being that my laptop couldn't utilize HAXM, and so I had to switch to a laptop with worse specs but with HAXM capabilities.

Comment: HAXM is like  KVM in Linux right?. But i think that HAXM is only for accelerate the simulation but i don't know that it was decisive for run it.

Comment: It might be similiar to KVM. But HAXM is specifically for speeding up Android emulation. Check out this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) to read Intel's description. There's an Ubuntu version.  I just know from experience that my gaming laptop without HAXM capabilities (but better specs) takes several minutes to boot up the 2.7'' QVGA on Gingerbread, while my other laptop with HAXM (and worse specs) can boot up the Nexus 7 on Lollipop with no problems.

Comment: Sorry, i have a 32bit system. But the problem i think that no is this because the problem not are the time it take, is that never start android os. Always he show android logo, for hours...